# Otimização de Aplicações Hibridas

Tags: javascript, css, ionic, apache-cordova, phonegap-buillder

posso durante um scroll de uma lista com muitos elementos, renderizar apenas os em tela, por intermédio de uma verificação do atual movimento de scroll que se cancela sozinha e criando uma div pai que tem seu height, setado manualmente com elementos de position absolute que tem sua altura setada manualmente, e intercalar entre display inline, inline-block, block contra o display none, dos que são renderizados ou não em tela e assim retirar o lag durante esses processos de scroll ?

Comment: Pode enviar um exemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara, a sua solução retiraria um pouco do "*lag*" (se tirar), pois mesmo essa solução precisa de otimização. Minha sugestão é usar (ou pesquisar um pouco sobre) o **Lazy Load** ([veja esse JS que maravilha](https://codepen.io/kvzivn/pen/MYKMVG)).
Agora, aqui vai ***uma dica*** pratica para criar apps de forma mais otimizadas *desde o inicio*:
O CSS nunca deve ser usado ao "*dinamizar*" algo com JS, a não ser que não haja outro jeito. A pesar do CSS3 estar bem "*dinâmico*" ele ainda é estático, dessa forma, para dinamizar uma aplicação (que é seu caso), use o máximo de JS e menos CSS que vc conseguir.
O conceito de *StyleSheet* é justamente **padronizar** o estilo para o JS dinamizar o **padrão**.